# Android Kotlin resize image inside collpasingtoolbarlayout appbarlayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Hi Guys I´m trying to **resize image** inside **collapsing toolbar layout** when user scroll appbar, but I can´t get that effect I have tried several code but not success, any help will be preaciated, thanks!

```
val mAppBarLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.app_bar) as AppBarLayout
mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(object : AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
    internal var isShow = false
    internal var scrollRange = -1

    override fun onOffsetChanged(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout, verticalOffset: Int) {
        if (scrollRange == -1) {
            scrollRange = appBarLayout.totalScrollRange
        }
        if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
            isShow = true
        } else if (isShow) {
            isShow = false
        }
    }
})
```

> **Problem : So how can I acheive resize image when collapsing toolbar layout**

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin Code for Detecting Collapsing toolbar State.

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->
           
            when {
                //  State Expanded
                verticalOffset == 0 -> //  Do anything for Expanded State
                //  State Collapsed
                abs(verticalOffset) >= appBarLayout.totalScrollRange -> //  Do anything for Collapse State
                else -> //  Do anything for Ideal State
            }
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            float offsetAlpha = (appBarLayout.getY() / appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange());
            ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "scaleX", offsetAlpha + 1);
            ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "scaleY", offsetAlpha + 1);
            scaleDownX.setDuration(0).start();
            scaleDownY.setDuration(0).start();
}
```

This code is represented in Java, but I think it is easy for you to parse the code to Kotlin.

Here the imageView's size got decreasing when scrolling down and vice versa